# How to insert into multiple columns of a table from a dropdown field

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have the following HTML code:

```
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>">
Faculty ID:<input type="text" name="fid" id="fid" value=""> 
<span class="error">*</span><br><br>
 Sunday: <select name="sun[]" id="sunday" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="11">8:15-9:15</option>
    <option value="12">9:15-10:15</option>
    <option value="13">10:15-11:15</option>
    <option value="14">11:15-12:15</option>
    <option value="15">12:15-1:15</option>
    <option value="16">1:15-2:15</option>
    <option value="17">2:15-3:15</option>
    <option value="18">3:15-4:15</option>
    <option value="19">4:15-5:15</option>
  </select>  
  <span class="error">*</span><br><br>
<button type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

How can I insert multiple values selected from the drop down list (sunday) into different columns?

For example, if 8:15-9:15 is selected then the value must be entered into the `s1` column into the  table, if 9:15-10:15 then it has to be entered into the `s2`column of my MySQL table and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Getting selected variable from dropdown list

```
$sunday = array('-select time--', '8:15-9:15', '9:15-10:15' and so on);
$selected_key = $_POST['sun'];
$selected_val = $sun[$_POST['sun']];
```

inserting data into into different table

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `" . $selected_val . "`
VALUES ('".$x"','".$y."','".$z."')";
```

Answer (score 0):

you can store the drop-down  options into keys of an array, which values is the column names. Then you can check which options were selected and add the corresponding columns to another array. Then you insert the data:

```
   $columns = array(
      "8:15-9:15" => s1,
      "9:15-10:15" => s2,
      "10:15-11:15" => s3,
      "11:15-12:15" => s4,
      "12:15-1:15" => s5,
      "1:15-2:15" => s6,
      "2:15-3:15" => s7,
      "3:15-4:15" => s8,
      "4:15-5:15" => s9
   ); //create a map between the options and column names

   //retrieve the selected options to an array 
   $selectedOptions = $_POST['sun'];

   $selectedColumns = array();

   if(count($selectedOptions)) {
     //add the column name for each selected option to an array
     foreach ($selectedOptions as $option) {
       $selectedColumns[] = $columns[$option];
     }
     // create a string with the columns names
     $columnsToInsert = implode(", ", $selectedColumns);
     // create a string with the selected options
     $valuesToInsert = implode("', '", $selectedOptions);
     // create the query string
     $query = "INSERT INTO your_table('$columnsToInsert') VALUES ('" . $valuesToInsert ."')";
     // then you execute the query
   }
```